# Removing duplicates from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This conserns two tables: "wp_extra_data" and "wp_posts". wp_extra_data has the fields "id", "post_id" and "post_title_md5". Now I need to figure out how to retrieve duplicates from "post_title_md5" and then *delete from wp_posts where id = wp_extra_data->post_id except for the oldest post_id (aka the one with the lowest ID*

Example:
wp_extra_data may contain:

```
ID post_id post_title_md5
23 45      322a85c7502dfb2fce5bbd6794c00f81
56 92      322a85c7502dfb2fce5bbd6794c00f81
75 12      322a85c7502dfb2fce5bbd6794c00f81
```

In which case I'd want the script to "remove from wp_posts where id = 92 and 12". So in short; how do I efficiently retrieve duplicates from wp_extra_data and then remove all of them except the one with the lowest key(ID). May be worth to note that I do not know what "post_title_md5" will be up front.

Comment: Do you mean you won't know the column name ahead of time, or you won't know the values contained in the column?

Comment: @George I mean I won't know the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("Delete from wp_posts where ID not in
(select post_id from wp_extra_data where id in(select min(ID)
from wp_extra_data
group by post_title_md5))")
```

Comment: I think this did what you asked... you wanted to remove any duplicates, so that each hash is unique... that's what this query does... what else are you looking for it to do?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors I need to make sure it deletes only the newest entries from wp_posts. This is determined by which row in wp_extra_data has the lowest ID - The oldest needs to stay, the rest needs to go.

Comment: So you don't want to delete from wp_extra_data, but from wp_posts, and they share ID's?

Comment: In table "wp_extra_data" the field "post_id" holds the value of the field "ID" in "wp_posts" so essentially I need to "delete from wp_posts where id = wp_extra_data->post_id" if you know what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I modified the example to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the duplicate hashes is easy:

```
SELECT post_title_md5
FROM wp_extra_data
GROUP BY post_title_md5
HAVING COUNT(post_title_md5) > 1
```

Then you can retrieve the post_id's using the above as part of a subquery:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_extra_data
WHERE (post_title_md5 IN (... previous query here ...));
```

However, this'll retrieve all the IDs with the duplicated hash. So you'd have to do some filter on this PHP-side and delete only the left-over IDs after you've eliminated the "first" one.

Comment: Thanks for that! Would an array + counter be efficient for that or am I making up stupid work-arounds again?